# Spring Cloud Gateway: Apply Custom Filter to RouterFunction

Tags: filter, spring-cloud-gateway, global-filter

In my spring cloud gateway I created a global filter that applies to standard routes fine, but I want to apply this same filter to a RouterFunction.

How do I go about passing my custom filter to the `RouterFunctions.route().filter()` ?

Answer (score -1):

This project provides an API Gateway built on top of the Spring Ecosystem, including: Spring 5, Spring Boot 2 and Project Reactor. Spring Cloud Gateway aims to provide a simple,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).